# Why is error occurs when trying to replace strings in an array with stars?

Tags: c++

It's not letting me replace the strings in the array and I have no idea why.

```
if (t1Array[n] == banArray[o])
{
   //t1Array[n] = "***";
   t1Array[n].replace(1, 2, 3, "***");
   banArrayCount[o] ++;
   t1filterfile << t1Array[n];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to replace 2 characters starting from position 1 of string `t1Array[n]` by 3 asterisks.

If so then the call will look as

```
t1Array[n].replace( 1, 2, 3, '*' );
```

This call corresponds to the following member function declaration

```
basic_string& replace(size_type pos, size_type n1, size_type n2, charT c);
```

Or you could use the following member function

```
basic_string& replace(size_type pos, size_type n1, const charT* s);
```

In this case the call will look as

```
t1Array[n].replace( 1, 2, "***" );
```

Take into account that positions start from `0`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstand the way `std::string::replace` works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string str = "0123456789";
    std::cout << str.replace(2,3,"***");
}
```

outputs `01***56789`. The number of characters that will be replace doesn't need to match the length of the string:

```
std::cout << str.replace(2,5,"*");
```

outputs `01*789`

Answer (score 0):

Replace function has the following prototype-

```
replace(starting location of replacement,number of characters to be replaced,a pointer to the string)
```